# Network disconnects after soft lockup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-kernel

I was running a system on Ubuntu Server 20.04 with an AMD Athlon 3200G and recently switched to a Ryzen 7 1800X. With the 3200G everything was fine, no issues whatsoever.

However, since I have switched to the new CPU, the network started disconnecting after some hours of uptime every time.

So I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04 and re installed all services (mostly some docker containers and reverse proxy inside docker). This however didn't fix the issue, same thing happened again.

When looking through journalctl, I noticed that approximately at the time the sytem started failing/disconnecting, there were several error messages mentioning a soft lockup and a CPU being stuck for ~20s (log is appended at the end). These messages would be logged roughly every 30s.

I wouldn't consider myself a beginner with standard linux usage, but my knowledge is fairly limited with kernels and I unfortunately cannot make any sense of the error messages.

Maybe someone knows what's going on or can help me decipher these messages, I'd be really glad if someone could help, thanks in advance!

```
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: Modules linked in: veth xt_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_nat aufs quota_v2 quota_tree nls_iso8859_1 dm_multipath scsi_dh_rd>
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  glue_helper r8169 i2c_piix4 realtek ahci libahci wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: CPU: 7 PID: 25166 Comm: (imesyncd) Tainted: G             L    5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450M S2H/B450M S2H, BIOS F50 11/27/2019
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RIP: 0010:smp_call_function_many+0x208/0x270
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: Code: 92 00 3b 05 de d2 70 01 89 c7 0f 83 9b fe ff ff 48 63 c7 48 8b 0b 48 03 0c c5 80 89 64 98 8b 41 18 a8 01 74 0a f3 90 8b 51 18 <83> e2 01 75 f6 eb c8 89 cf 48 c7 c2 20 b8 a>
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff9e2643fe7b60 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RAX: 0000000000000003 RBX: ffff892ffe9ebd40 RCX: ffff892ffe8323e0
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RDX: 0000000000000003 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RBP: ffff9e2643fe7ba0 R08: ffff892ffcc38538 R09: ffff892ffcc38ec0
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: R10: ffff892ffcc38538 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffff97281930
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000020
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: FS:  00007fea61f31980(0000) GS:ffff892ffe9c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: CR2: 000055bd11646d18 CR3: 00000003e8150000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  ? load_new_mm_cr3+0xf0/0xf0
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  on_each_cpu+0x2d/0x60
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  flush_tlb_kernel_range+0x38/0x90
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  __purge_vmap_area_lazy+0x70/0x6d0
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  _vm_unmap_aliases+0xf5/0x130
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  vm_unmap_aliases+0x19/0x20
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  change_page_attr_set_clr+0xcf/0x200
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  set_memory_ro+0x29/0x30
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  bpf_int_jit_compile+0x2d1/0x340
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  bpf_prog_select_runtime+0xa7/0x130
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  bpf_prepare_filter+0x44c/0x4b0
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  ? hardlockup_detector_perf_cleanup+0xa0/0xa0
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  bpf_prog_create_from_user+0xc7/0x120
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  seccomp_set_mode_filter+0x11c/0x740
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  do_seccomp+0x39/0x200
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  __x64_sys_seccomp+0x1a/0x20
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fea62dfe89d
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d c3 f5 0>
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffec565caa8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000013d
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055bd117d1f20 RCX: 00007fea62dfe89d
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RDX: 000055bd11794d60 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000001
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: RBP: 000055bd11794d60 R08: 000055bd117d1f20 R09: 00007fea62c73350
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Jul 19 17:21:16 ld-nas kernel: R13: 00007ffec565cad0 R14: 00007fea62c73dd0 R15: 00007ffec565cf50
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_sched detected expedited stalls on CPUs/tasks: { 7-... } 242419 jiffies s: 5425 root: 0x1/.
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel: rcu: blocking rcu_node structures: l=1:0-15:0x80/.
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel: Task dump for CPU 7:
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel: (imesyncd)      R  running task        0 25166      1 0x8000000c
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? bpf_int_jit_compile+0x2d1/0x340
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? bpf_prog_select_runtime+0xa7/0x130
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? bpf_prepare_filter+0x44c/0x4b0
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? hardlockup_detector_perf_cleanup+0xa0/0xa0
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? bpf_prog_create_from_user+0xc7/0x120
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? seccomp_set_mode_filter+0x11c/0x740
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? do_seccomp+0x39/0x200
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? __x64_sys_seccomp+0x1a/0x20
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
Jul 19 17:21:43 ld-nas kernel:  ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jul 19 17:21:44 ld-nas kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 23s! [(imesyncd):25166]
-- Reboot --
```

If you require any more information (about the system or more logs), I'd be glad to provide them for you.

---

**EDIT**:
After updating my BIOS to the latest version, the system appeared to be running more stable and longer without failure. However, there seems to be a new issue which now causes a hard lockup (of another CPU).

```
Jul 21 00:02:36 ld-nas kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.3: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
Jul 21 00:02:36 ld-nas kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.3: Host halt failed, -110
Jul 21 00:02:36 ld-nas kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.3: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Jul 21 00:02:36 ld-nas kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.3: HC died; cleaning up
Jul 21 00:02:36 ld-nas kernel: usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jul 21 00:02:36 ld-nas kernel: usb 4-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jul 21 00:02:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16457 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:03:36 ld-nas systemd-udevd[617]: sdd: Worker [49959] processing SEQNUM=12062 is taking a long time
Jul 21 00:03:36 ld-nas systemd-udevd[617]: hiddev0: Worker [49962] processing SEQNUM=12069 is taking a long time
Jul 21 00:03:36 ld-nas systemd-udevd[617]: 0003:046D:C52B.0001: Worker [49960] processing SEQNUM=12063 is taking a long time
Jul 21 00:03:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16459 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:04:15 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 3min)!
Jul 21 00:04:15 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Killing process 1134 (systemd-logind) with signal SIGABRT.
Jul 21 00:04:31 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 3min)!
Jul 21 00:04:31 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Killing process 1073 (systemd-resolve) with signal SIGABRT.
Jul 21 00:04:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16461 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:05:36 ld-nas systemd-udevd[617]: sdd: Worker [49959] processing SEQNUM=12062 killed
Jul 21 00:05:36 ld-nas systemd-udevd[617]: hiddev0: Worker [49962] processing SEQNUM=12069 killed
Jul 21 00:05:36 ld-nas systemd-udevd[617]: 0003:046D:C52B.0001: Worker [49960] processing SEQNUM=12063 killed
Jul 21 00:05:45 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: State 'stop-watchdog' timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:05:49 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 5min)!
Jul 21 00:05:49 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Killing process 1123 (snapd) with signal SIGABRT.
Jul 21 00:05:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16463 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:06:02 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: State 'stop-watchdog' timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:06:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16465 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:07:15 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:07:15 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Killing process 1134 (systemd-logind) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:07:19 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: State 'stop-watchdog' timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:07:32 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:07:32 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Killing process 1073 (systemd-resolve) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:07:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16467 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:08:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:08:50 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:08:50 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Killing process 1123 (snapd) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:08:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16469 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:09:02 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:09:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16471 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:10:16 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:10:16 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Killing process 1134 (systemd-logind) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:10:20 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:10:32 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:10:32 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Killing process 1073 (systemd-resolve) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:10:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16474 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:11:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
Jul 21 00:11:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
Jul 21 00:11:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jul 21 00:11:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Jul 21 00:11:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
Jul 21 00:11:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Found left-over process 1134 (systemd-logind) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:11:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:11:46 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jul 21 00:11:50 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:11:50 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Killing process 1123 (snapd) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:11:53 ld-nas kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:0c:8e:29:0e:d8:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=16475 PROTO=2
Jul 21 00:12:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
Jul 21 00:12:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
Jul 21 00:12:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jul 21 00:12:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Jul 21 00:12:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Found left-over process 1073 (systemd-resolve) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:12:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:12:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Jul 21 00:13:17 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:13:20 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
Jul 21 00:13:20 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
Jul 21 00:13:21 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jul 21 00:13:21 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:13:21 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 1123 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:13:21 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:13:21 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Jul 21 00:13:21 ld-nas systemd-udevd[617]: Worker [49959] terminated by signal 9 (KILL)
Jul 21 00:13:21 ld-nas systemd-udevd[617]: sdd: Worker [49959] failed
Jul 21 00:13:33 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:14:47 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:14:47 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Killing process 1134 (systemd-logind) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 1123 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 50071 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:14:51 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Jul 21 00:15:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:15:03 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Killing process 1073 (systemd-resolve) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:16:17 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:16:21 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:16:21 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 21 00:16:21 ld-nas systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:16:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jul 21 00:16:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:16:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 1123 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:16:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:16:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 50079 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:16:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:16:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Jul 21 00:16:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:17:47 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:17:47 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Killing process 1134 (systemd-logind) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 1123 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 50087 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:17:52 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Jul 21 00:18:04 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul 21 00:18:04 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Killing process 1073 (systemd-resolve) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Found left-over process 1134 (systemd-logind) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:19:18 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jul 21 00:19:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:19:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 21 00:19:22 ld-nas systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:19:23 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 21 00:19:23 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:19:23 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 1123 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:19:23 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:19:23 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 50095 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:19:23 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:19:23 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Jul 21 00:19:23 ld-nas snapd[50100]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Jul 21 00:19:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
Jul 21 00:19:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 21 00:19:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
Jul 21 00:19:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Jul 21 00:19:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Jul 21 00:19:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Found left-over process 1073 (systemd-resolve) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:19:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:19:34 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Jul 21 00:20:48 ld-nas systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 1123 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over process 50109 (snapd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Jul 21 00:20:53 ld-nas snapd[50115]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 12
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: Modules linked in: veth xt_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_nat aufs quota_v2 quota_tree nls_iso8859_1 dm_multipath scsi_dh_rd>
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  hid_generic usbhid hid nouveau crct10dif_pclmul mxm_wmi crc32_pclmul video ghash_clmulni_intel i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper aesni_intel syscopyarea sysfillrect crypto_simd s>
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: CPU: 12 PID: 50109 Comm: systemd-detect- Not tainted 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450M S2H/B450M S2H, BIOS F61c 05/10/2021
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RIP: 0010:smp_call_function_single+0x9b/0x110
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: Code: 65 8b 05 90 81 6d 64 a9 00 01 1f 00 75 79 85 c9 75 40 48 c7 c6 c0 bc 02 00 65 48 03 35 46 19 6d 64 8b 46 18 a8 01 74 09 f3 90 <8b> 46 18 a8 01 75 f7 83 4e 18 01 4c 89 c9 4>
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb4c60448fba0 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: 0000010da42e2b19 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff8d02eeb2bcc0 RDI: 0000000000000001
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RBP: ffffb4c60448fbe8 R08: ffffffff9b846090 R09: 0000000000000000
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 006f666e69757063 R12: 0000000000000001
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: R13: 00002b8a84bbd593 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff8d02e3fd5f00
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: FS:  00007fde6214c980(0000) GS:ffff8d02eeb00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: CR2: 0000562bbe2c2d98 CR3: 00000002577a6000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  aperfmperf_snapshot_cpu+0x42/0x50
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  arch_freq_prepare_all+0x67/0xa0
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  cpuinfo_open+0x13/0x30
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  proc_reg_open+0x77/0x130
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  ? proc_put_link+0x10/0x10
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  do_dentry_open+0x143/0x3a0
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  vfs_open+0x2d/0x30
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  do_last+0x194/0x900
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  path_openat+0x8d/0x290
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  ? putname+0x4a/0x50
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  do_filp_open+0x91/0x100
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  ? __alloc_fd+0x46/0x150
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  do_sys_open+0x17e/0x290
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  __x64_sys_openat+0x20/0x30
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fde62ff9eab
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: Code: 25 00 00 41 00 3d 00 00 41 00 74 4b 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 67 44 89 e2 48 89 ee bf 9c ff ff ff b8 01 01 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 0f 87 91 00 00 00 48 8b 4>
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffeaa449770 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000101
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000562bbe2c12d0 RCX: 00007fde62ff9eab
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RDX: 0000000000080000 RSI: 00007fde62e6b227 RDI: 00000000ffffff9c
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: RBP: 00007fde62e6b227 R08: 0000000000000008 R09: 0000000000000001
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000080000
Jul 21 00:04:29 ld-nas kernel: R13: 00007fde62e92e21 R14: 00007fde62e6b869 R15: 00007fde62e6b88c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are known issues with Ryzen and Linux. Are you ssh'd into this machine? If you Google "ryzen linux soft lockup" there are hundreds of threads about the system freezing and requiring a reboot, but not a single thread mentioned intermittent network connectivity as a symptom.

[This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=245608) explains that adding

```
processor.max_cstate=5 rcu_nocbs=0-15
```

to your kernel's boot options might fix the issue.

[This](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208201) bug report looks identical to your problem. Same CPU and same kernel. A good thing to do anyway is to update your bios (yours is from 2019). Some people claim this is a power problem when the CPU is idle, and suggest playing around with whatever power settings are in your bios could resolve the lockups.

The last thing to try if all else fails is to get in contact with AMD and see if they'll give you an RMA.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendations! I installed the newest BIOS version and it first appeared to have fixed the soft lockup problem. The system lasted significantly longer without a crash, before it was ~4-5h, now it can handle ~12 hours. I cannot say that updating the bios has something to do with it, but I guess that's the case. However, there seems to be a new problem causing some services (like snapd) to crash. I'll append the new log to my original question, I'd be glad if you could take a look!

Comment: If a new problem has appeared, please post it in a new question. Also, if my answer solved the soft lockup problem, please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Thanks Isaac, I finally managed to fix the problem: After a lot of trying I disabled SMT and C6 state in BIOS. The system now runs without failure for over 3 days. I still have the kernel parameters loaded though.